# Reading date and hour with an specific format

Tags: c, scanf

I have been working on a program that reads a string which is supossed to be the date and the time with the following format dd-yy-aaaa hh:mm:ss. It does it n times, and at the end it prints the number of strings that were entered in the correct format. I haven't been able to make it only count the dates that have, for example, the year on a four digit format. It counts them as long as the data entered are numbers. How do i fix it?
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char string[100];
    int day[10];
    int month[10];
    int year[10];
    int hour[10];
    int minute[10];
    int second[10];
    int n,i=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    while(n!=0){
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &string);
    fflush(stdin);
        if((sscanf(string,"%d%d-%d%d-%d%d%d%d %d%d:%d%d:%d%d",day,month,year,hour,minute,second))==6){
        i++;
    }
    n--;
    }
    printf("%d",i);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will make your life a lot easier if you use `strptime`, i.e.:

From the manpage:

> NAME
>
> ```
>   strptime - convert a string representation of time to a time tm structure
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE       /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
>   #include <time.h>
>
>   char *strptime(const char *s, const char *format, struct tm *tm);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The `strptime()`  function is the converse function to `strftime`(3) and converts the character string pointed to by `s` to
>   values which are stored in the tm structure pointed to by `tm`, using the format specified by `format`.  Here `format` is a
>    character string that consists of field descriptors and text characters, reminiscent of `scanf(3)`.  Each field descriptor consists of a `%` character followed by another character that specifies the replacement for the  field descriptor.
>   All  other  characters in the format string must have a matching character in the input string, except for whitespace,
>   which matches zero or more whitespace characters in the input string.  There should be whitespace  or  other  alphanumeric characters between any two field descriptors.

And so it continues ...

Answer (score 1):

A few notes to clarify:

1. Why are `day` etc. arrays of length 10?  Do you expect `n <= 10` and to save each date?
2. You need a `return` statement.
3. Is `i` supposed to be the number of successfully parsed dates?

Ok, so there are some problems with the way you're using `sscanf` (but yay for checking the return value!) - here's the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html).

1. `sscanf` must have the address to which you want to read the input - so `&day[i]` presumably.
2. `%d` will read the whole `int`, not just one digit - that is,

   ```
     sscanf(string, "%d", &my_int_var);
   ```

will read the first `int` it encounters, whether that be 1, 10, 1987, 2008875, etc.

Comment: 1. No, i do not expect the values to be 10 digits or less, it was just a randon value that i used. 2. I added the return statement already. 3. Yes. I will make corrections to the program, but i still haven't foud the way to make it count strings with the correct format only.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. to fix

```
char string[100];
int day;
int month;
int year;
int hour;
int minute;
int second;
int n,i=0;
scanf("%d", &n);
fflush(stdin);//non-portable
while(n>0){
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", &string);
    fflush(stdin);
    if((sscanf(string,"%2d-%2d-%4d %2d:%2d:%2d", &day,&month,&year,&hour,&minute,&second))==6){
        //range check
        ++i;
    }
    --n;
}
printf("%d", i);
```

Comment: `%d` does not interpret as an octal number.

Comment: @kbshimmyo If you think the number that begins with 0 and is interpreted in octal then perform the following tests: `scanf("%d", &n);/* input 010 */ printf("%d", n);/* display 10, not 8 */`

Comment: `%2d` : `2` reading - Specifies the maximum length of the field.

Comment: But what if it has to be one lenght only? It shouldn't accept, for example, years with less than four digits. Not only with a maximum of four digits.

Comment: @ÁngelCáceresLicona one length of digits will accept this program. (I already wrote in the comments), Please check the range if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` to read data and then parse using `sscanf()` features:
`"%*1d%*1d"` to detect 2 digits,
`"%*1[ ]"` to detect space
`"%n"` for the correct length and ending.

```
// 1 good, 0 bad
int CheckDate(const char *buffer) {
  static const char format[] = "dd-yy-aaaa hh:mm:ss\n";
  #define Space "%*1[ ]"
  #define Dig2 "%*1d%*1d"
  #define Dig4 Dig2 Dig2
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buffer, Dig2 "-" Dig2 "-" Dig4 Space Dig2 ":" Dig2 ":" Dig2 "%n", &n);
  return (sizeof(format) - 2 == n) && (buffer[n] == '\n');
}

int main() {
  int i = 0;
  int n = 0;
  scanf("%d%*c", &n);
  while (n-- > 0) {
    char buffer[100];
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) break; // EOF
    i += CheckDate(buffer);
  }
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```